# How to get user information from a MYSQL local database

Tags: php

Hey i need to get information from a database and display it on my index.php.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('users');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['age'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
</body>
</html>
```

however this will show the information for all of the users in the database.
I have a primary key in the database, which is the account number, could we use this to only display information about that account on the page only? 
I will also need to save the details into variables on the php page so some guidance doing that would be greatfull.

Thanks Oliver

Comment: Yep, just change the query to include `WHERE id=?`. I'd recommend changing to mysqli, so that you can prepare and execute this instead.

Comment: Please change the code and resend it to me? thats would be absolutely awesome, just put an example i will work out what i need form my database.

Comment: For a quick solution, try putting `WHERE id=1` (assuming your primary key column is named id). See if that will output only one row of information.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'WHERE' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\textme.php on line 8

Problem

Comment: Omg it worked, thanks but now how do i make it so when they log in the WHERE UserNameID=23 is set to the correct value? maybe in the actual login script when the login is successfull save it to a variable?

Comment: @OliverKetley you'll have to grab their username and password from the submitted form and compare it with the one in the database, so your where clause will be `WHERE Username=$username` AND Password=$password, then the id can be saved to a session variable, do some research on building a login page with php

Comment: Stop using http://php.net/mysql_query **Warning:**
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.

Comment: what do you recomend i do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve data according to a specific user you must explicitly tell mysql. So, add WHERE id={the I'd u want the info for}.

For your second question. "How do u get the id when the user logs in".

The answer to this is you can (a) how a session initialized at login or (b) how another file or even a loop in the script you need the Id for to run a query for the users name and then you get the Id.

The draw backs of option b is that you are slowing this done and are doing alot of call which can crash your overall site.

The choice is your this is how you can get a particular I'd for a user.

Comment: If u post all of your code I can explicitly tell u how to get I'd.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Oliver'); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('users');

$query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE username='$login_session'"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['sex'] . "</td><td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['password'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I got the WHERE username="$login_session"
and the login_session value is a unique value for each of the users in the database so it can never be the same, so i can use this to pull up information for that user only

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables to store the information in the case you are working with sessions, if not, you can use a regular variable to store the information or maybe use post or get variables

Comment: Thanks I have just set this up with sessions, great tip!